# Do I need to add a foreign key Id property on mvc models code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two classes

```
public class Shop
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public virtual Shop Shop {get;set;}

   //Do i need this line as well?
   public int ShopId {get;set;}
}
```

My question is, do I need to define the ShopId? I see many code samples out there and sometimes it is there and sometimes it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use ShopId property for foreign key. But if you don't add ShopId, Enitiy Framework itself create a foreign key property named TableName_TableEntityId.

Answer (score 0):

A **Shop** can have many **Product** and the **Shop** class has a List
property to allow you to access those **Products** from a particular shop. Additionally, the  Product class has a  Shop property, so that you can see what  **Shop** is associated with a particular  **Product**. Code First recognizes this *one-to-many relationship* between  **Shop** and  **Product** and, by convention, determines that the **Products** table will need a foreign key in order to persist its knowledge of which **Shop** a **Product** belongs to.
`Code First` create a foreign key in the database using the pattern  `[Name of navigation property]_[Primary Key of related class]`(i.e.,
Shop_ShopId). And thanks to some additional metadata that Code First
built, `Entity Framework` will know to use that *Foreign Key* when querying from or
saving to the database.

```
public class Shop
{
   public int ShopId { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public virtual Shop Shop {get;set;}

}
```